# How to properly mock a react component class that has components in its properties?

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs

I need to mock a component on jest, the component structure is like this:

```
export class ClassName extends React.Component<ClassNameProps> {
  static PropOne;
  static PropTwo;

  static MethodOne(param: string): void;
  static MethodTwo(param: string): void;
}
```

**Note**: Each of those static properties on it, return a different react component. So PropOne is a component

**Note 2**: I'm not the responsable for this component, and I don't have the permission to change it.

On my mock files, I usually do something like:

```
export default {
  ClassName: 'class-name'
}
```

But in this case, I need to mock those sub components as well. I've already tried the following ideas:

```
ClassName: {
  PropOne: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('')),
  PropTwo: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('')),
  MethodOne: jest.fn(),
  MethodTwo: jest.fn(),
},

ClassName: class ClassName extends Component<ClassNameProps> {
  static PropOne: Component<ClassNameProps>|string = 'class-name.prop-one';
  static PropTwo: Component<ClassNameProps>|string = 'class-name.prop.two';
  
  static MethodOne = jest.fn();
  static MethodTwo = jest.fn();
},
```

P.S.: This component is part of a additional package. They are not on my project.

Comment: You _don't_ mock them. They're part of the thing you're supposed to be testing.

Comment: Not those, because they're part of a installed package. I did run `yarn add myPackage` to use this component. I've already done the tests of the components that belongs to my project.